# how to transform a itertools.permutations to a dataframe in ptyhon?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permutation, python-itertools

I need to change a itertools.permutations into a format that i can use, such a dataframe or list, is possible to create a dataframe with itertools.permutations

how to transform a itertools.permutations to a dataframe in ptyhon?

```
from itertools import permutations 
perm_5 = permutations(alphabet, 5)
```

No idea what can i do with a itertools.permutations it give the permutation but for some reason in the tutorials only show how to print, and i need it to save it in a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from itertools import permutations 
import pandas as pd

perm_5 = permutations(alphabet, 5)
df = pd.Dataframe(list(perm_5))
```

Or as suggested in comments by @sj95126,

```
pd.DataFrame({"perm":perm_5})
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({"perm":perm_5})` would avoid iterating millions of elements twice.

Comment: Agreed. That would be more performant